# Coalesce and nullif to handle substring and null values

Tags: sql, sql-server-2016

I'm using COALESCE with NULLIF to handle datetime from a field but still get the subtring vlaues in the output for empty string

```
select coalesce(nullif('20' + LEFT(SUBSTRING(cancelTime,1,8),2)
+ '/' + LEFT(RIGHT(SUBSTRING(canceltime,1,8),5),2) + '/' +  RIGHT(SUBSTRING(cancelTime,1,8),2)+' '+
left(SUBSTRING(cancelTime,10,17),2)
+ ':' + right(left(SUBSTRING(cancelTime,10,17),5),2) + ':' +  right(SUBSTRING(cancelTime,10,17),2),''),'') as CancelDate
  FROM [dbo].[test]
```

Logic: I want to show the date and time whenever there is a date time in the field if there is no value then show it as blank. For example when the value is 19/05/19 22:46:05 then show this 2019/05/19 22:46:05.

Sample data from Canceltime field:

canceltime

```
Blank
19/05/19 22:46:05
```

---

Error output:

```
20 / /  ::
2019/05/19 22:46:05
```

---

Expected output:

```
Blank
2019/05/19 22:46:05
```

I'm expecting the 20 / /  :: to be blank in the output.

Comment: You should provide sample data and describe the logic you want to implement.  An appropriate database tag is also helpful.

Comment: I have provided sample data if that helps @GordonLinoff

Comment: What database engine? Is it SQL Server, Sybase?

Comment: @TheImpaler SQL server 2016

Comment: As a rule of thumb, avoid storing date/time data as `VARCHAR`. Use `DATETIME` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CASE` to identify "bad" values and produce results in specific cases. For example:

```
select
  case when cancelTime 
      like '[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9] [0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]'
    then ... -- your long formatting formula here
    else '' -- blank if it doesn't match a date/time value
  end as CancelDate  
from [dbo].[test]
```

Anyway, as a rule of thumb, avoid storing date/time data as `VARCHAR`. Use a proper data type, such as `DATETIME`, `SMALLDATETIME`, or `DATETIME2`.

Comment: Thank you. I'm curious to see how I can get it working without the CASE and while using COALESCE and NULLIF. Is it possible that way?

Comment: `COALESCE()` detects null values. However, you don't seem to have null values at all in your table, but empty `VARCHAR`s (strings with length 0) instead. `COALESCE()` won't do anything with them.

Comment: What can I use instead of the COALESCE then to detect null values?

Comment: In any case, data manipulation is sketchy at best and you are fighting a losing battle. You better start using a proper data type as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend just handling things as date/times in their native format.  But in your case, can't you just prepend `'20'`?

```
select '20' + canceltime
```